# Connection Error while sending message to RabbitMQ server on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I have my RabbitMQ Server running on AWS EC2
I have run the producer and consumer code locally. It is working.
I am able to access the rabbitMQ management web app as well.

When I am trying to push data from my laptop to EC2
I am getting this error on this line:

```
 connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('xx.xx.xx.xx',5672,'/',credentials))
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in **init**
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed

where xx.xx.xx.xx: public IP address of my instance

Pls tell me,  if I am using the correct parameters. What should be the IP address , virtual hostname.
I have checked  the credentials , the user that I am using exists and it has the rights to access '/' virtual host

I have made the needed changes in the Security Groups.
This is a screenshot of it:

[image]

When I am running the same producer code from within the instance it's working properly. No Exceptions and the consumer is able to receive it as well.

This is my complete code for reference:

```
import pika
print("Start")
credentials=pika.PlainCredentials('manish','manish')#RabbitMQ user         created on EC2
   connection=pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('xx.xx.xx.xx',5672,'/',credentials)) 
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
               routing_key='hello',
               body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `socket_timeout` and it worked for me, you could try something like :

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username,'password')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('hostname',port,'virtual host',credentials,**socket_timeout=10000**))
```